# Why I cannot see my WordPress site when I am logged out?

Tags: wordpress

I am creating a WordPress theme in the localhost. I do not know why I see a white screen when I logout from the dashboard.

If I login again into the dashboard I can visit the site again. Everything is working good.

Note: If I change the theme, the issue is gone by then.

Comment: define( 'WP_DEBUG', false ) can add this in wp-config to check

Comment: Setting `WP_DEBUG` to `false` will only disable the display of PHP warning/error messages on screen, something that won't help OP understand what's going on. Rajan, if switching themes fixes the problem then the issue is clearly being caused by your theme. [Enable the debug.log file](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/), visit your homepage while logged out, then check the log.

Comment: Any console log messages in your Chrome Dev tools?

Comment: No. Nothing.
Enabled error debugging feature and disabled.
And deleted all plugins. Nothing is changed.

Answer (score 2):

There might be some Error in the new theme you are creating.

You can go to Wordpress root directory "wp-config.php" file and add a line

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true )
```

That will display you the error instead of the white screen.

Comment: Nothing showing even after enabling WP_DEBUG to true. I already tried.

Answer (score -1):

define( 'WP_DEBUG', false ) can add this in wp-config to check